# Error in Service with MediaPlayer when rotated the device

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

any sugestion to make a VideoPlayer (for a HLS stream) who retain the buffer status on rotating the device? I was making a service always in background and handling the surface attach when rotating the device, but doesn't work. I loose the video (the audio still working) and get the error : E/MediaPlayer(28347): error (1, -2147483648) 
The videoView is in a fragment with setRetainInstance(true); enabled

Any idea?  it's this idea possible?

Answer (score 1):

The Aplication get newly created on rotate check methods like onStop onResume
which get called in case of rotate.

Take care that you don't launch the service twice

[Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Comment: the problem isn't the service, the problem is changing the SurfaceHolder for the video on the fly. I can't deattach de surface when it's destroyed and set again when the service is connected and the surface is created. I tried pausing the video before call setDisplay(null) and play it again when y set the display (or surface).